# Get lat lon from static map using scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get the coordinates (lat, lon) from a static map embedded on a website using Scrapy. When i inspect the element, i found the coordinates right
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqmt1.png), but I don't know how to get it

I used `response.xpath ('//img[@id="static-map"]/@src').extract()`

and I get

```
'//maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-12.119641500000000,-77.011014800000000&zoom=16&markers=-12.119641500000000,-77.011014800000000&key=AIzaSyB42QzVvI4Fz1sQMlJBHemUlH5zYH0VMIE&size=780x456&sensor=true&scale=2&signature=dl39BZVBkcNsfHm0FjeNzKw1puU='
```

And I want to get in two different colums the lat and lon (-12.11964 , -77.011014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath you can use substring functions (and *1 to remove ending zeros) :

```
lat = response.xpath ('substring-after(substring-before(//img[@id="static-map"]/@src,","),"=")*1').extract()
lon = response.xpath ('substring-after(substring-before(//img[@id="static-map"]/@src,"&"),",")*1').extract()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse url

```
import urllib.parse

url = '//maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-12.119641500000000,-77.011014800000000&zoom=16&markers=-12.119641500000000,-77.011014800000000&key=AIzaSyB42QzVvI4Fz1sQMlJBHemUlH5zYH0VMIE&size=780x456&sensor=true&scale=2&signature=dl39BZVBkcNsfHm0FjeNzKw1puU='

query = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url).query
data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(query)
lat, lon = eval(data['center'][0])
print(lat, lon)
```

Or you can treat it as normal text and `split()` it

```
url = '//maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-12.119641500000000,-77.011014800000000&zoom=16&markers=-12.119641500000000,-77.011014800000000&key=AIzaSyB42QzVvI4Fz1sQMlJBHemUlH5zYH0VMIE&size=780x456&sensor=true&scale=2&signature=dl39BZVBkcNsfHm0FjeNzKw1puU='

lat, lon = eval(url.split("center=")[1].split('&')[0])
print(lat, lon)
```